# It's a bad idea to add localhost in the url of launching projects - Warning

Tags: wamp, warnings

I have a program called ‘project’ that I run from wamp, and everything goes correctly, the problem is that I'm getting the following warning every time I launch wamp:

```
It's a bad idea to add localhost in the url of launching projects. It is best to define VirtualHost in
wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.37/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
file and not add localhost in the url.
```

I know there are similar questions with solutions, I have been reading several forums with solutions to solve the problem but I can not get the warning to disappear. In httpd-vhosts.conf I have the following:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Can you help me solve it? I get the same warning even if I replace 'localhost' in serverName and ServerAlias with: `C:/wamp64/www/project/`

My wamp version is 3.1.7 - 64bit:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Within `c:\wamp64\wampmanager.conf` under `[options]` you should see `urlAddLocalhost = "on"`, try switching its value to `off` and restart WAMP.

I'm sorry that I couldn't find any documentation that explains it. I know it because I was looking for something that could link my projects directly from `http://localhost` and tracked this option from the WAMP scripts. When I enabled it the warning started to show.

PS.: I'm afraid this method I described works only for WAMPSERVER >v3.1